# Python Lambda behaviour

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to get my head around lambda expressions, closures and scoping in Python. Why does the program not crash on the first line here?

```
>>> foo = lambda x: x + a
>>> foo(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
>>> a = 5
>>> foo(2)
7
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's just not how Python functions work; it's not special to lambdas:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   return x + a
>>> foo
<function foo at 0xb7dde454>
>>> foo(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Variables are looked up when used, not when a function is defined.  They are even looked up each time the function is called, which you will definitely find unexpected if you're coming from a C background (for example), but this isn't a problem in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Your lambda expression doesn't get evaluated until you call it.

It does get parsed, which is why a syntax error would cause a traceback.

```
>>> foo = lambda x : x + a
>>> bar = lambda y : print y
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables in Python may be used before they are set.  This will generate a runtime error, not a syntax error.  Here's an example using local variables:

```
>>> def f():
...     return a
...     a = 3
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

This is in contrast to languages which consider dereferencing an unassigned or undefined variable a syntax error.  Python doesn't "capture" the current state of lexical scope, it just uses references to mutable lexical scopes.  Here's a demonstration:

```
>>> def f(): return a
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
>>> a = 3
>>> f()
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The bodies of lambdas (and functions defined with def) in Python are not evaluated until they are called.  Names are always looked up at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

on the first line you create expression, which is different from evaluating it.  When you try to evaluate it, this is then it cannot find symbol a .